# How to make program wait till user has inputted data on another form

Tags: c#

Here is excerpt from form one:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> SelectedMem = new List<string>();
    frmSelectMembers SelectMembers = new frmSelectMembers(SelectedMem);
    SelectMembers.Show();
    for (int member = 0; member < SelectedMem.Count; member++)
    {

    }
}
```

Currently the program just continues onto the for loop once 'SelectMembers' (the form in which the user inputs the data) is opened.

What'd be the best way to make the program wait till the user has inputted items into the list?

Could I just check if the list is not empty?

Comment: If you want to perform the insert after some action takes place on the other form, then put the code which performs in the insert into a handler for that action.  Presumably there's some button on the other form which the user clicks?

Comment: Does the SelectMembers form do anything aside from get the information from the user?

Comment: You would also do well to omit the db related stuff from your question if all you're asking about is how to wait until the data has been submitted

Comment: @SamIam The user is presented with a list-view box, they can then select using the check boxes certain rows. these are then added to the List SelectedMem when the user clicks a button.

Comment: @DanielGrist  does the form go away when the user clicks the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open `SelectMembers` with the `DialogResult` property set for some value. Then, you can manage whatever you want to do once that DialogResult is set. For example:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> SelectedMem = new List<string>();
    frmSelectMembers SelectMembers = new frmSelectMembers(SelectedMem);

    if(SelectMembers.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this waits until a DialogResult is found
    {
          //DO WHATEVER YOU NEED IN HERE
          string text = SelectMembers.TextBox1.Text;
    }
    SelectMembers.Dispose();
}
```

Also, if you want to get the value of some textbox, you have to set the `Modifiers` property of the TextBox to public. Then you can access as the example above.

Comment: You need to call `.Dispose()` on a form shown with `.ShowDialog()`, as noted in the remarks at [Form.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx).

Comment: @NicoRiff How could I set DialogResult.OK in the second form?

Comment: On the SelectMembers form select the control that will fire the DialogResult. For example the 'OK' or 'Cancel' Button, and in Properties window you´ll find the DialogResult property. Whenever that button is pressed it will fire that DialogResult.

Comment: I understand that however the button also has code to be run when the button is pressed. If I set the DialogResult Property onto this button then that code won't run, will it?

Comment: If you set the property via the properties window your code won´t execute. If you want some code to be executed on the button click, then you can set the DialogResult programatically after you´ve done everything you need to do with the button click, and then, set the DialogResult this way: this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

Comment: @NicoRiff Thanks!